# using MVC controller as webService

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, jstree

here is my project hirarchy:

[image]

from browser.js I'm trying to call ManagerController:

```
 $("#jstree").jstree({
        "json_data": {

    "ajax": {   


                type: "GET",
                async: true,
                "url": "Controllers/Manager/Getlocations?userId='1234'",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                cache: false,
                success: function (msg) {                         
                        return msg;
                },
                error: function () {
                    // TODO process error
                }
            },

//continuation is less relevant
```

But I get the following error in chrome console:

> GET
>   http://localhost:1186/MainUgi/Controllers/Manager/Getlocations?userId='1234'&_=1324071607446
>   404 (Not Found)

1) what should be the right path ?

2) what is the `&_=1324071607446` which is concatinated to the end of my get request?

**update**

my controller looks like:

```
  public class ManagerController : Controller
    {

        public JsonResult GetLocations(string userId)
        {
            var locationsJson = 
            new {[  {"data": "[0]", .. some data...}  ]};

            return Json(locationsJson, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

my request looks like:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:1186/MainUgi/Controllers/Manager/Getlocations?userId=1234
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found
Request Headersview source
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Charset:windows-1255,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:he-IL,he;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Host:localhost:1186
Referer:http://localhost:1186/MainUgi/browser.htm
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.63 Safari/535.7
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Query String Parametersview URL encoded
userId:1234
Response Headersview source
Cache-Control:private
Connection:Close
Content-Length:2346
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Fri, 16 Dec 2011 22:00:37 GMT
Server:ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
```

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic MVC url mask is the following:

```
/{CONTROLLER}/{ACTION}?{...PARAMETERS}
```

By your example we have:

```
'/manager/getLocations?userId=1234'
```

And the controller should have the following code (example):

```
[ControllerAction]
public void getLocations( int userId ) {
    ViewData["UserId"] = userId;
    RenderView("GetLocations");
}
```

Now you need to have a view file to show the content. Create a folder (inside the root of the project), named "View", and inside it, create another one with the name of the controller (Manager), and create a view file called "GetLocations.aspx" (the one that we want asked to render).

To print the UserId variable in the view:

```
<%= ViewData["UserId"] %>
```

If it doesn't work, it's better for you to read a lot about the MVC Pattern. You can start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410269.aspx).

Comment: I'm trying to use the contoller as webService only. Not the whole MVC pattern

Comment: I did. but I'll recheck on that

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully this will help:

1. Try removing the single quotes from `userId='1234'` --> `userId=1234`
2. The `_=1324071607446` parameter is jQuery appending a timestamp to the end of the request URL to prevent caching (notice how you've used `cache: false`).

Answer (score 0):

Try separating the url and the data into two separate commands:

```
url:  "Controllers/Manager/Getlocations",
data: { userId: '1234' }
```

Also try marking the method as [HttpGet] in case you have that method overloaded.

Comment: I don'r have overload and I use GET so I'm not sure the splitting will work. I'll try